# Mysql Join two tables get relevent data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am developing a site where there are two tables. **orders** and **shipper**.
A very basic structure is as below,

```
orders
=======
order_id
shipper_id
customer_id
order_date
order_item

shipper
=========
shipper_id
shipper_name
```

I want to list all orders along with it's shipper name. for example

```
order_id | customer_id | order_date | order_item | shipper_name
```

There are 2 rows (two orders) in orders table and 3 rows (three shippers) in shipper table now.

When I run following query but It shows duplicate records. That is, 2 orders 3 times ( 2*3 = 6 rows). why isn't just 2 orders and with shipper information?

```
SELECT * FROM orders o, shippers s ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

Note : This query works however, but I am not sure weather it's standard way to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM orders o, shippers s GROUP BY o.order_id ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

I have heard of table joins. Is this situation where joins are used ?  I have developed many dynamic websites but really this question confuses me.

Comment: U have no join happening. It can't read your mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join can be used in your query as below :

```
select orders.order_id, orders.customer_id, orders.order_date, orders.order_item, shipper.shipper_name from orders left join shipper on orders.shipper_id=shipper.shipper_id;
```

or you can use as below :

```
select o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.order_date, o.order_item, s.shipper_name from orders o left join shipper s on o.shipper_id=s.shipper_id;
```

Comment: An alias might be useful

Comment: Nice. Results are as expected. I'm pro in programing but noob in db :(

Comment: @SohanPatel: That's great. It helped you.. :) Also accept my answer.